# Express the indefinite integral $\int e^{-x^2}dx$ using function $\Phi(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

Express the indefinite integral $\int e^{-x^2}dx$ using function $\Phi(x)$.
$\Phi(x)$ is the following special function:

$$\Phi(x) = \frac12 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$$

Comment: What if I do not want ?

Comment: In other words, what work have you done on this problem so far? What are your thoughts? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Perfom the change of variable $t=\sqrt{2}\:u$ in the integrand of $Φ$, you get
$$
\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2}dt=\sqrt{2}\int_0^{x/\sqrt{2}} e^{-u^2}du
$$ then you find
$$
Φ(x) = 1/2 +(1/\sqrt{π})\int_0^{x/\sqrt{2}} e^{-u^2}dt
$$ giving
$$
\int_0^x e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{π}\:Φ(\sqrt{2}\:x)- \sqrt{π}/2. 
$$ Then observe that
$$
\int e^{-u^2}du=\int_0^x e^{-u^2}du+C
$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is really easy to get!

Comment: You are welcome.